# Connection state with doowb/angular-pusher

Tags: angularjs, pusher

I am trying to build an Angular project with Pusher using the `angular-pusher` wrapper. It's working well but I need to detect when the user loses internet briefly so that they can retrieve missed changes to data from my server.

It looks like the way to handle this is to reload the data on `Pusher.connection.state('connected'...)` but this does not seem to work with `angular-pusher` - I am receiving "Pusher.connection" is undefined.

Here is my code:

```
angular.module('respondersapp', ['doowb.angular-pusher']).

    config(['PusherServiceProvider',
        function(PusherServiceProvider) {
            PusherServiceProvider
                .setToken('Foooooooo')
                .setOptions({});
        }
    ]);
var ResponderController = function($scope, $http, Pusher) {
    $scope.responders = [];

    Pusher.subscribe('responders', 'status', function (item) {
        // an item was updated. find it in our list and update it.
        var found = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.responders.length; i++) {
            if ($scope.responders[i].id === item.id) {
                found = true;
                $scope.responders[i] = item;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            $scope.responders.push(item);
        }
    });
    Pusher.subscribe('responders', 'unavail', function(item) {
        $scope.responders.splice($scope.responders.indexOf(item), 1);
    });
    var retrieveResponders = function () {
        // get a list of responders from the api located at '/api/responders'
        console.log('getting responders');
        $http.get('/app/dashboard/avail-responders')
            .success(function (responders) {
                $scope.responders = responders;
            });
    };

    $scope.updateItem = function (item) {
        console.log('updating item');
        $http.post('/api/responders', item);
    };

    // load the responders
    retrieveResponders();
};
```

Under this setup how would I go about monitoring connection state? I'm basically trying to replicate the Firebase "catch up" functionality for spotty connections, Firebase was not working overall for me, too confusing trying to manage multiple data sets (not looking to replace back-end at all).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `Pusher` dependency only exposes `subscribe` and `unsubscribe`. See:
https://github.com/doowb/angular-pusher/blob/gh-pages/angular-pusher.js#L86

However, if you access the `PusherService` you get access to the `Pusher` instance (the one provided by the Pusher JS library) using `PusherService.then`. See:
https://github.com/doowb/angular-pusher/blob/gh-pages/angular-pusher.js#L91

I'm not sure why the `PusherService` provides a level of abstraction and why it doesn't just return the `pusher` instance. It's probably so that it can add some of the Angular specific functionality (`$rootScope.$broadcast` and `$rootScope.$digest`).

Maybe you can set the `PusherService` as a dependency and access the `pusher` instance using the following?

```
PusherService.then(function (pusher) {
  var state = pusher.connection.state;
});
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of how this might work? I'm new to Angular, finding all of these real time services difficult to implement without just the most basic capabilities. Looking at PubNub now, also appears to have its set of challenges.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify @leggetters answer, you might do something like:

```
app.controller("MyController", function(PusherService) {
  PusherService.then(function(pusher) {
    pusher.connection.bind("state_change", function(states) {
      console.log("Pusher's state changed from %o to %o", states.previous, states.current);
    });
  });
});
```

Also note that [pusher-js](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-js) (which angular-pusher uses) has `activityTimeout` and `pongTimeout` configuration to tweak the connection state detection.

From my limited experiments, connection states can't be relied on. With the default values, you can go offline for many seconds and then back online without them being any the wiser.

Even if you lower the configuration values, someone could probably drop offline for just a millisecond and miss a message if they're unlucky.